# How to Collapse Left Side Padding or Margin in Responsive Design Layout?

Tags: css, margin, padding

PROBLEM:

I'm currently working on a from-pdf template; I'm relatively new to responsive design and am having an issue with the following: I have a button at the bottom of the page that I'm currently centering using a set margin-left value. However doing so prevents that button from 'floating' all the way to the left during screen re-size.

GOAL:

Have a solution that allows the button to be horizontally centered during 'full size' browser, but collapse and float all the way to the left when the browser size is decreased.

TRIED:

- Setting padding/margin
- Setting both of the above to auto
- Thought about a horrible conceptual ghetto hack (I could technically make the image a long white rectangle with the button centered then make the image fluid, thus re-sizable)

WEBSITE IN QUESTION (OBJECT: ORANGE BUTTON NEAR FOOTER):

http://thedma.org/the-state-of-data/

Comment: In general, don't put links to websites for people to look at your code. Once its fixed its impossible for future question seekers to see what the issue was, and therefore if the selected answer is relevant to them.

Comment: I did not put the website up so that people look at my code, I put it up so they could see the issue visually, but point taken.

Comment: Why did I receive a -1?

Comment: Not entirely sure; however, they're plenty of questions regarding media queries on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use media queries for this. Specifically viewport-height or viewport-width from the sounds of things.

[Link to documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

Basic idea:

```
@media (max-height: 600px) {
    .bottom-button {
        /* styles */
    }
}
@media (min-height: 600px) {
    .bottom-button {
        /* different styles */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1ytjszd7/)

The trick is:

```
a {
    display: block;
   text-align: center;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

assuming that `a` selects the link corresponding to the button and `img` is your image.

Comment: That's a great trick Le_Morri, but I'm not sure that it will work if the element is not within a link. Thank you for the solution pertaining to this situation as it worked great cross-browser